# With Flash + Adobe Media Server, how do I access a video on a directory other than _definst_

Tags: flash, video-streaming, adobe-media-server

I'm using`Adobe Media Server 5` to stream my videos.

I can connect to my app and play videos by calling

`NetConnection.connect([rtmp link]/[application])`

And then

`NetStream.play([name of video])`

All the files that I play by using this method are in `[application]\streams\_definst_\`

If I want to play a file from, say `\streams\output` instead, how would I do that?

I tried creating an `Application.xml` with `storageDir` set to the `output` directory, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it with my Application.xml file

```
<Application> 
    <StreamManager> 
        <VirtualDirectory> 
            <Streams>/;[path to app]streams\output</Streams>
        </VirtualDirectory>
    </StreamManager> 
</Application>
```

This, however, changes the default file that streams publish to as well.